# What's wrong with \ifcase in my command?

Tags: context

I'm pretty new user of ConTeXt, for writing my courses.
I've wrote a command to generate a titlepage. I want to pass some optionnal parameters.

```
%#1 is used for cover color,
%#2 is used for changing color of title
%#3 is for title
%#4 is for author name
%#5 is optional - for rotating title (0-90-270 degree)
%#6 is optional - for displaying an image centered on page

\def\TitlePage[#1][#2]#3#4#5#6
  {
  \definelayout[cover][backspace=10mm,topspace=25mm,width=19cm,height=27cm]
  \definelayer[site2][x=10mm, y=10mm, width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]
  \definelayer[site][x=60mm, y=10mm, width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight, corner={top,right}]
  \definelayer[logo][x=.5\paperwidth-2.5cm, y=.5\paperheight-2.5cm, width=5cm, height=5cm]

  \definefont[BigFont][SansBold at 60pt]
  \definefont[MedFont][SansBold at 30pt]
  \definefont[SmallFont][SansBold at 14pt]
  \definecolor[bkg][{#1}]
  \definecolor[Gray][s=#2]

  \setlayer[site2]{\externalfigure[logo2.png][width=5cm]}
  \setlayer[site]{\externalfigure[logo.png][width=5cm]}

  \ifcase#6\relax
    \setlayer[logo]{\externalfigure[{#6}] [width=5cm, height=5cm]}
  \fi

  \setupbackgrounds[page][background={color,site,site2,logo},backgroundcolor=bkg]
  \startstandardmakeup
    \dontcomplain
    \BigFont \setupinterlinespace \vfill \setupalign[left] \let\\=\par

    \ifcase#5\relax
      \noindent\color[Gray]{#3}\par
    \else
      \noindent\rotate[rotation=#5]{\color[Gray]{#3}}\par
    \fi

    \SmallFont\color[Gray]{#4}
  \stopstandardmakeup
\setupbackgrounds[page][background=]
\setuplayout[reset]
}
```

In my document, I want to write

```
\TitlePage[r=.5, g=.5, b=.5][.45]{Title of course}{Author}{90}{python.png}
```

or

```
\TitlePage[r=.5, g=.5, b=.5][.45]{Title of course}{Author}{}{python.png}
```

or

```
\TitlePage[r=.5, g=.5, b=.5][.45]{Title of course}{Author}{90}{}
```

or

```
\TitlePage[r=.5, g=.5, b=.5][.45]{Title of course}{Author}{}{}
```

But only the first would work (if I remove \ifcase commands)
Anyone would help me ?
Thanks !
(Sorry for my bad English :( )

Comment: `\ifcase` is not for looking whether an argument is not empty. Use `\ifx\relax#6\relax`

Comment: To check for the sixth argument you can use `\doifsomething{#6}{...}` and for the fifth argument `\doifsomethingelse{#5}{...}{...}` or `\doifnumberelse{#5}{...}{...}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not really an answer to the question, but the ConTeXt way of doing such things is to use keys and values.  Here I define a bunch of keys using `\setvariables` and retrieve the values using `\getvariable`.  This makes a much cleaner interface and allows you to easily specify sensible defaults for all the values.

```
% Add default to the set of locations to get access to ConTeXt's beautiful
% sample pictures
\setupexternalfigures[location={default,local,global}]

\definelayout
  [cover]
  [backspace=10mm,
   topspace=25mm,
   width=19cm,
   height=27cm]

\definelayer
  [site2]
  [x=10mm,
   y=10mm,
   width=\paperwidth,
   height=\paperheight]

\definelayer
  [site]
  [x=60mm,
   y=10mm,
   width=\paperwidth,
   height=\paperheight,
   corner={top,right}]

\definelayer
  [logo]
  [x=.5\paperwidth-2.5cm,
   y=.5\paperheight-2.5cm,
   width=5cm,
   height=5cm]

\definefont[BigFont][SansBold at 60pt]
\definefont[MedFont][SansBold at 30pt]
\definefont[SmallFont][SansBold at 14pt]

% Defaults for the title page

\setlayer[site2]{\externalfigure[hacker.jpg][width=5cm]}
\setlayer[site]{\externalfigure[mill.png][width=5cm]}

\setvariables
  [TitlePage]
  [color={r=.5, g=.5, b=.5},
   gray={.45},
   title={oeps},
   author={oeps},
   rotate={0},
   image={}]

% typesetting the title page

\unexpanded\def\TitlePage{\dosingleempty\doTitlePage}
\def\doTitlePage[#1]{%
  \setvariables[TitlePage][#1]%
  %
  \edef\TitlePageColor{\getvariable{TitlePage}{color}}%
  \edef\TitlePageGray{\getvariable{TitlePage}{gray}}%
  \edef\TitlePageRotate{\getvariable{TitlePage}{rotate}}%
  \edef\TitlePageImage{\getvariable{TitlePage}{image}}%
  %
  \expanded{\definecolor[bkg][\TitlePageColor]}%
  \expanded{\definecolor[Gray][s=\TitlePageGray]}%
  %
  \doifsomething{\TitlePageImage}{%
    \setlayer[logo]{\externalfigure[\TitlePageImage][width=5cm, height=5cm]}%
  }%
  %
  \setupbackgrounds
    [page]
    [background={color,site,site2,logo},
     backgroundcolor=bkg]%
  %
  \startstandardmakeup
    \dontcomplain
    \BigFont\setupinterlinespace
    \setupalign[left]
    \let\\=\par

    \noindent\rotate[rotation=\TitlePageRotate]{\color[Gray]{\getvariable{TitlePage}{title}}}\par

    \SmallFont\color[Gray]{\getvariable{TitlePage}{author}}
  \stopstandardmakeup
  %
  \setupbackgrounds[page][background=]
  \setuplayout[reset]
}

\starttext

\TitlePage
  [color={r=.5, g=.5, b=.5},
   gray=.45,
   title={Title of course},
   author={Author},
   rotate=90,
   image={cow.pdf}]

\stoptext
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Thanks !
I'm trying to use ConTeXt with the wiki, but it's kinda obsolete for some things.
I've changed my macro for this

```
\doifsomething{#6}
{
  \setlayer[logo]{\externalfigure[{#6}] [width=5cm, height=5cm]}
}
```

and

```
\doifnumberelse{#5}
  {
    \noindent\rotate[rotation=#5]{\color[Gray]{#3}}\par
  }
  {
    \noindent\color[Gray]{#3}\par
  }
```

Now it's working !

Thanks guys !